# PHPMailer conflicts with login

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have deployed PHPMailer in my `PHP` project without using composer.

I can get it to work but strangely at the expense of my login which all of a sudden *does not* authenticate with this error.

Warning: require_once(../resources/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ecom_march/ecom/resources/functions_contactus.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../resources/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ecom_march/ecom/resources/functions_contactus.php on line 7

I am wondering what might cause the conflict or if I am instantiating this library incorrectly.

**functions_contactus.php**

```
 <?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


    require_once '../resources/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';

    require_once '../resources/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

    require_once '../resources/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';



    function send_email_from_contact_form() {


        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {



            $name = $_POST['fullname'];
            $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['fullname'])); 
            $name = escape_string($_POST['fullname']); 



            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])); 
            $email = escape_string($_POST['email']); 


            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $message = strip_tags(trim($_POST['message'])); 
            $message = escape_string($_POST['message']); 



            $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // create a new instance of the PHPMailer class created
            $mail->isSMTP(); 

            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
            $mail->Port = 587; 
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
            $mail->Username = "chrisdorman1978@gmail.com"; // google username
            $mail->Password = "blablabla"; // 


            $mail->setFrom($email); // send us the users email address
            $mail->addAddress('chrisdorman1978@gmail.com'); // all emails will be sent to me at this address




            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = '<h1 align=text-center>Name : '.$_POST['fullname']. '<br>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br>Message: '.$_POST['message'].'</h1>';



            if ($mail->send())
                echo("  Your email has been sent");
            else
                echo("Sorry, your email has NOT been sent");

        }




    }/////////////////////////////end of send_email_from_contact_form*
```

Comment: Failed opening is pretty clear - the required file simply could not be found.

Comment: but I am already including the file and the code works but it fails the login

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the current working directory (which depends on the invocation script).